# FormValidation.io with bootstrap select

Tags: bootstrap-select, formvalidation.io

I'm using Boost strap 4 and the bootstrap select jQuery plugin.

Im trying to integrate FormValidation.io with my forms. I have got everything working with normal input fields but cant figure out how to integrate it with the select field.

I would like it to be a required field and display the tick icon once a selection has been made.

my FormValidation.io code :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
const mydropzone = document.getElementById('mydropzone');

const RoleIdField = jQuery(mydropzone.querySelector('[name="roleId"]'));    

const fv = FormValidation.formValidation(mydropzone, {    
       
    
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'First Name is required'
                    },                        
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'First Name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            last_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Last Name is required'
                    },                        
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'First Name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            roleId: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select a Role'
                    },  
                }
            },
           
        },
        plugins: {
            trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
            bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
            submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
            icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
                valid: 'fa fa-check',
                invalid: 'fa fa-times',
                validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            }),
        }
    }
);
});


$('#roleId').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
// Revalidate the color field when an option is chosen
fv.revalidateField('roelId');
});
```

My form ID is 'mydropzone' and my select name and id are 'roleId'

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the developers who answered my email, anyone else that needs to know how this is done:

add this to your css file :

```
.bootstrap-select i.fv-plugins-icon {
right: -38px !important;
```

then configure your js like this :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
$('#gender').selectpicker();

const demoForm = document.getElementById('demoForm');
FormValidation.formValidation(demoForm, {
    fields: {
        gender: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The gender is required'
                }
            }
        },
    },
    plugins: {
        trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
        submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
        bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
        icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
            valid: 'fa fa-check',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
          }),
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case `.invalid-feedback` display CSS is none. so I have changed it into `block`

```
.bs_selectpicker_div .invalid-feedback {
    display: block !important;
}
```